# How to use types with lifetimes in Expr::apply closures?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

The following function will fail to compile because `foo` needs to be `'static` to work in the closure. However it is clear in this example that `foo` will outlive the aggregation just fine. Since we cannot used scoped threads here, is there a way in either safe or unsafe rust to allow you to use such types?

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

struct Foo<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
}

fn process<'a>(df: DataFrame, foo: Foo<'a>) -> DataFrame {
    let foo = Arc::new(foo);

    df.lazy()
        .group_by(["idx"])
        .agg([col("col1").apply(move |s| agg_fn(s, foo.clone()), Default::default())])
        .collect()
        .unwrap()
}

fn agg_fn(_s: Series, _foo: Arc<Foo>) -> PolarsResult<Option<Series>> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { a: "hello" };
    let df = df!(
        "idx" => [1, 1, 3],
        "col1" => [5.0, 3.0, 1.0],
    )
    .unwrap();

    let result = process(df, foo);
    println!("Result: {result:#}");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polars `Expr` doesn't have a lifetime so anything you put inside must be `'static`, so there is no direct solution to your problem.

The `Arc` trick doesn't work because you end up having a `Arc<Foo<'a>>` that is no better than the original one for your problem.

The easiest fix would be to avoid the lifetime in `Foo` in the first place. In your particular example the inner value is a `&'static str` but I guess that is just an example artifact. If you could that value into a `Box` or `Arc` instead of the whole Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
    a: Arc<str>,
}
```

Then the lifetime will just disappear.

There is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ce9c653597e09373b1afb7fcb4a8128) with a simplified version of your problem and this solution.

If you like to live risky, you *can* lie to the compiler and get away with it, sometimes. Just don't complain when your program eventually blows up in flames (it will, I know ;-).

I cannot recommend this line of work, because you are breaking the rules, but here it is anyways:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    unsafe fn transmute_static(x: Self) -> Foo<'static> {
        std::mem::transmute(x)
    }
}
```

And now you can call it instead of using an `Arc`:

```
   //let foo = Arc::new(foo);
   let foo = unsafe { Foo::transmute_static(foo) };
```

It this transmute sound? Well, I think the jury is still out, and people smarter than me don't seem to agree in that point. But for now it seems to work. Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea0506023559b9bff7189ba9e9466c5e) with a simplified version of your issue and this hacky solution.